# How to read LAS header or read only some attributes of LAZ file with LAStools/C++

Tags: point, lidar, las, lastools

It takes lots of time when reading laz files when you iterate hundreds of laz file. But reading only the header can only takes less than 100 ms to read hundreds of las files.

The same problems arises when reading all attributes of laz files. The time it cost to decompress all the attributes is too much. Is there any method to read only attribute wanted? For example：only read the `X` can read faster？

```cpp
class LASLIB_DLL LASreader
{
public:
  LASheader header;
  LASpoint point;

  I64 npoints;
  I64 p_count;

  //[...]

  BOOL read_point() { return (this->*read_simple)(); };

  //[...]
}
```

```cpp
for (int i = 0 ; i < 1000 ; i++)
{ 
   lasReader->read_point();
   LASpoint& pointReader = lasReader->point;
   double x = pointReader.get_x();
}
```

If I want to read any attribute of laz file， I have to decompress whole things of class `LASreader`. That's just too slow and make no-sense.

Answer (score 1):

To read only the header this is how I proceed. My code interfaces the result with the R language so don't be surprised by the `List` or `CharacterVector`. You can change it to fit your need. You can retrieve the entire source code [here](https://github.com/Jean-Romain/rlas/blob/master/src/readheader.cpp).

```cpp
std::string filestd = as<std::string>(file);

LASreadOpener lasreadopener;
lasreadopener.set_file_name(filestd.c_str());

LASreader* lasreader = lasreadopener.open();
LASheader* lasheader = &lasreader->header;

if((0 == lasreader) || (NULL == lasreader))
  throw std::runtime_error("LASlib internal error. See message above.");

char cguid[38];
sprintf(cguid, "%08x-%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x%08x",
   lasheader->project_ID_GUID_data_1,
   lasheader->project_ID_GUID_data_2,
   lasheader->project_ID_GUID_data_3,
   *((U16*)(lasheader->project_ID_GUID_data_4)),
   *((U16*)(lasheader->project_ID_GUID_data_4+2)),
   *((U32*)(lasheader->project_ID_GUID_data_4+4)));

CharacterVector guid(cguid);

List head(0);
head.push_back(lasheader->file_signature);
head.push_back(lasheader->file_source_ID);
head.push_back(globalencodingreader(lasheader));
head.push_back(guid);
head.push_back((int)lasheader->version_major);
head.push_back((int)lasheader->version_minor);
head.push_back(lasheader->system_identifier);
head.push_back(lasheader->generating_software);
head.push_back(lasheader->file_creation_day);
head.push_back(lasheader->file_creation_year);
head.push_back(lasheader->header_size);
head.push_back(lasheader->offset_to_point_data);
head.push_back(lasheader->number_of_variable_length_records);
head.push_back((int)lasheader->point_data_format);
head.push_back(lasheader->point_data_record_length);
// [...]
```

To selectively decompress some attribute `LASzip` defines some stuff but I don't know where and how to use it. The source code is [here](https://github.com/LAStools/LAStools/blob/150e6c23bb2ced93083b5ba656c5f8e55403b81b/LASzip/src/laszip_decompress_selective_v3.hpp). There is something in [LASreadOpener](https://github.com/LAStools/LAStools/blob/45c04870e018dcaa30254a2e854fc0be6d2f38ae/LASlib/inc/lasreader.hpp#L222) called `void set_decompress_selective(U32);`. But it seems it applies only to LAS 1.4 according to the comment L326 `// optional selective decompression (compressed new LAS 1.4 point types only)`

```cpp
#define LASZIP_DECOMPRESS_SELECTIVE_ALL                0xFFFFFFFF

#define LASZIP_DECOMPRESS_SELECTIVE_CHANNEL_RETURNS_XY 0x00000000
#define LASZIP_DECOMPRESS_SELECTIVE_Z                  0x00000001
#define LASZIP_DECOMPRESS_SELECTIVE_CLASSIFICATION     0x00000002
#define LASZIP_DECOMPRESS_SELECTIVE_FLAGS              0x00000004
#define LASZIP_DECOMPRESS_SELECTIVE_INTENSITY          0x00000008
#define LASZIP_DECOMPRESS_SELECTIVE_SCAN_ANGLE         0x00000010
#define LASZIP_DECOMPRESS_SELECTIVE_USER_DATA          0x00000020
#define LASZIP_DECOMPRESS_SELECTIVE_POINT_SOURCE       0x00000040
#define LASZIP_DECOMPRESS_SELECTIVE_GPS_TIME           0x00000080
#define LASZIP_DECOMPRESS_SELECTIVE_RGB                0x00000100
#define LASZIP_DECOMPRESS_SELECTIVE_NIR                0x00000200
#define LASZIP_DECOMPRESS_SELECTIVE_WAVEPACKET         0x00000400
#define LASZIP_DECOMPRESS_SELECTIVE_BYTE0              0x00010000
#define LASZIP_DECOMPRESS_SELECTIVE_BYTE1              0x00020000
#define LASZIP_DECOMPRESS_SELECTIVE_BYTE2              0x00040000
#define LASZIP_DECOMPRESS_SELECTIVE_BYTE3              0x00080000
#define LASZIP_DECOMPRESS_SELECTIVE_BYTE4              0x00100000
#define LASZIP_DECOMPRESS_SELECTIVE_BYTE5              0x00200000
#define LASZIP_DECOMPRESS_SELECTIVE_BYTE6              0x00400000
#define LASZIP_DECOMPRESS_SELECTIVE_BYTE7              0x00800000
#define LASZIP_DECOMPRESS_SELECTIVE_EXTRA_BYTES        0xFFFF0000
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I will strive to figure out the _DECOMPRESS_SELECTIVE. And post here if succeed.

Comment: Recently, I have test the selective decompress fuc of lastools. And post it here! Thanks again! 
@JRR

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I have test the selective decompress fuc of lastools.
And, there's some time can save.
Here is the notice and test result.
notice:

1. lasitem_version>3。
2. las_version = 1.4
   use:

```c
lasReaderOpener.set_decompress_selective(laszip_DECOMPRESS_SELECTIVE_CHANNEL_RETURNS_Z);//for more section to see laszip_decompress_selective_v3.hpp
```

test result:

compress all:

[image]

only 56% time takes!

compress selective:

[image]